# Custom @Query in SpringBoot using MongoDB error com.mongodb.util.JSONParseException(uPDATED)

Tags: json, mongodb, spring-boot

Using MongoDB with Java

> Please note this cutom query is only made to see how it functions ,so please don' t tell me there are alternatives in hibernate (I already know that ,I just want to run it)

Error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at repository.serviceclass.getjsondatamongo(serviceclass.java:25)
    at springbootwebsocketexample.SpringBootWebsocketExampleApplication.main(SpringBootWebsocketExampleApplication.java:58)
```

> For UR HELP 
>   (serviceclass.java:25) ==    `return userrep2.obj1();`
>   SpringBootWebsocketExampleApplication.java:58=== `JSONObject jsOn1=cc1.getjsondatamongo();`
>
> Here is my repository.UserRepository.java

```
package repository;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.*;
import org.json.*;

//import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.*;

import com.mongodb.connection.*;
import document.Users;
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<Users,Integer> {




    @Query("db.users.find()")
    JSONObject obj1(); 
}
```

> Here is my repository.serviceclass

```
package repository;

import java.util.*;

import org.json.*;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.stereotype.*;
import document.*;
@Service
public class serviceclass {
    @Autowired
    UserRepository userrep2;
    public JSONObject getjsondatamongo()
    {
        return userrep2.obj1();
    }
}
```

> Here is my SpringBootWebsocketExampleApplication.java

```
package springbootwebsocketexample;

import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.*;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.stereotype.*;
import repository.*;
import document.Users;
import repository.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.*;
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages= {"resource"})
@ComponentScan(basePackages= {"document"})
@ComponentScan(basePackages= {"repository"})
@ComponentScan(basePackages= {"config"})
public class SpringBootWebsocketExampleApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    public serviceclass cc1 ;
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootWebsocketExampleApplication.class, args);

    }


      @Override
        public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
             List<Users> kk=new ArrayList<Users>();
             JSONObject jsOn1=cc1.getjsondatamongo();
             System.out.println(jsOn1);
        }
}
```

**UPDATION**
I HAVE UPDATED MY SpringBootWebsocketExampleApplication.java above 
New Error = Caused by: com.mongodb.util.JSONParseException: db.users.find()

```
15:45:36.951 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.settings.DevToolsSettings - Included patterns for restart : []
15:45:36.954 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.settings.DevToolsSettings - Excluded patterns for restart : [/spring-boot-starter/target/classes/, /spring-boot-autoconfigure/target/classes/, /spring-boot-starter-[\w-]+/, /spring-boot/target/classes/, /spring-boot-actuator/target/classes/, /spring-boot-devtools/target/classes/]
15:45:36.954 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls - Matching URLs for reloading : [file:/C:/Users/vaibhav.chhabra/Documents/workspace-sts-3.9.7.RELEASE/DB_Mongo_exapme_name/target/classes/]

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::       (v1.5.10.RELEASE)

2019-02-12 15:45:37.110  INFO 3048 --- [  restartedMain] s.SpringBootWebsocketExampleApplication  : Starting SpringBootWebsocketExampleApplication on VNL-VaibhavC with PID 3048 (C:\Users\vaibhav.chhabra\Documents\workspace-sts-3.9.7.RELEASE\DB_Mongo_exapme_name\target\classes started by vaibhav.chhabra in C:\Users\vaibhav.chhabra\Documents\workspace-sts-3.9.7.RELEASE\DB_Mongo_exapme_name)
2019-02-12 15:45:37.110  INFO 3048 --- [  restartedMain] s.SpringBootWebsocketExampleApplication  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-02-12 15:45:37.150  INFO 3048 --- [  restartedMain] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@1599273b: startup date [Tue Feb 12 15:45:37 IST 2019]; root of context hierarchy
2019-02-12 15:45:38.032  INFO 3048 --- [  restartedMain] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2019-02-12 15:45:38.038  INFO 3048 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-02-12 15:45:38.039  INFO 3048 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.27
2019-02-12 15:45:38.089  INFO 3048 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-02-12 15:45:38.089  INFO 3048 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 941 ms
2019-02-12 15:45:38.183  INFO 3048 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2019-02-12 15:45:38.185  INFO 3048 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2019-02-12 15:45:38.186  INFO 3048 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2019-02-12 15:45:38.186  INFO 3048 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2019-02-12 15:45:38.186  INFO 3048 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2019-02-12 15:45:38.448  INFO 3048 --- [  restartedMain] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Cluster created with settings {hosts=[localhost:27017], mode=MULTIPLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
2019-02-12 15:45:38.448  INFO 3048 --- [  restartedMain] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Adding discovered server localhost:27017 to client view of cluster
2019-02-12 15:45:38.489  INFO 3048 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:1, serverValue:225}] to localhost:27017
2019-02-12 15:45:38.490  INFO 3048 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=localhost:27017, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[4, 0, 5]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=7, maxDocumentSize=16777216, roundTripTimeNanos=459434}
2019-02-12 15:45:38.491  INFO 3048 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Discovered cluster type of STANDALONE
2019-02-12 15:45:38.622  WARN 3048 --- [  restartedMain] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'springBootWebsocketExampleApplication': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'cc1'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'serviceclass': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userrep2'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.mongodb.util.JSONParseException: 
db
^
2019-02-12 15:45:38.626  INFO 3048 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2019-02-12 15:45:38.634  INFO 3048 --- [  restartedMain] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-02-12 15:45:38.641 ERROR 3048 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'springBootWebsocketExampleApplication': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'cc1'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'serviceclass': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userrep2'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.mongodb.util.JSONParseException: 
db
^
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at springbootwebsocketexample.SpringBootWebsocketExampleApplication.main(SpringBootWebsocketExampleApplication.java:65) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'serviceclass': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userrep2'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.mongodb.util.JSONParseException: 
db
^
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.mongodb.util.JSONParseException: 
db
^
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    ... 37 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.mongodb.util.JSONParseException: 
db
^
    at com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.parse(JSON.java:230) ~[mongodb-driver-3.4.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.parse(JSON.java:155) ~[mongodb-driver-3.4.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.util.JSON.parse(JSON.java:92) ~[mongodb-driver-3.4.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.util.JSON.parse(JSON.java:73) ~[mongodb-driver-3.4.3.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.StringBasedMongoQuery$ParameterBindingParser.parseAndCollectParameterBindingsFromQueryIntoBindings(StringBasedMongoQuery.java:230) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.StringBasedMongoQuery.<init>(StringBasedMongoQuery.java:93) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.StringBasedMongoQuery.<init>(StringBasedMongoQuery.java:72) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoRepositoryFactory$MongoQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(MongoRepositoryFactory.java:169) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:449) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:222) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:277) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:263) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(MongoRepositoryFactoryBean.java:117) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    ... 47 common frames omitted
```

Comment: @Pijotrek I did them both still no effect

Comment: I deleted my comment and put an answer, please try it and tell if it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotate your repository class with `@Repository`.

Also, do not do that:

```
ServiceClass cc1 = new ServiceClass();
```

instead, this should be injected with `@Autowired` annotation to let Spring framework do its job, like this:

```
public class SpringBootWebsocketExampleApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private ServiceClass serviceClass;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootWebsocketExampleApplication.class, args);

    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
         List<Users> kk=new ArrayList<Users>();
         JSONObject jsOn1=cc1.getjsondatamongo();
         System.out.println(jsOn1);
    }

}
```

This is the spring approach. Additional reading: https://www.baeldung.com/inversion-control-and-dependency-injection-in-spring

And a small piece of advice: follow naming conventions/standards. Classes should be named with a capital letter, camel cased, i.e. `UserRepository`, `UserService`

## part2:

Assuming from your newer/current exception. I think there is a problem with parsing the query result into `JSONObject`. I am not sure about this but usually you want to return list of POJOs, i.e: `List<User>`.

Also, you could probably use "built in" methods such as `findAll()` - no need to use `native query` here. Try this:

```
@Service
public class ServiceClass {
    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;
    public JSONObject getjsondatamongo()
    {
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

## part3

Going through some internet tutorials and reading docs, I think you should simply ommit `db.collection.find()` and just provide `{}` in your `@Query`. Like `@Query("{}")` if you want to have the whole data returned.

Comment: Well Anotation is not allowed in the main class , no idea why it is so ,it says " The annotation @Autowired is disallowed for this location"

Comment: are you sure you are using it in correct place? It should be used for field, not inside the main method.

Comment: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'springBootWebsocketExampleApplication': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'cc1'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'serviceclass': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userrep2'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:

Comment: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.mongodb.util.JSONParseException: 
db.users.find()

Comment: Ok, another problem but we are 1 step closer. Could you edit your post with current stacktrace please?

Comment: Sure I will do it

Comment: I know this already I have put this in my question as well  Please note this cutom query is only made to see how it functions ,so please don' t tell me there are alternatives in hibernate (I already know that ,I just want to run it). Later on I WILL MODIFY IT SO PLEASE DON'T TELL ME THE HIBERNATE METHOD

Comment: Ok, I WILL NOT TELL YOU THE HIBERNATE METHOD. Did you try changing return type to `List<User>` instead of `JSONObject`?

Comment: Yes i changed the return type to List<Users> everywhere , still the same error.

Comment: ok NOW i WANT to get results of people between id from 4 to 100 having name starting with J having salary 20+ and more than 10000 other conditions ,so Please tell me how to do this using Custom Query instead oF HIBERNATE

Comment: `@Query("{ 'id' : { $gt: ?0, $lt: ?1 } }")
List<User> findUsersInIdRange(int fromId, int toId)` . You basically need to learn the query language, operators (here `$and`) etc. I am glad you have your example working.

Comment: It is ok ,part 3 is giving me errors like hell ,so remove part 3 not working . BTW I have accepted your answer